# Why does API Gateway not have permissions for my Authorizer lambda when using Swagger?

Tags: swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have an API defined using Swagger, which defines the following API Key authorizer:

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: x-api-key
    in: header
    x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: "oauth2"
    x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
      type: token
      authorizerUri: arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:[accountid]:function:ApiKeyAuthorizerLambdaFunction/invocations
      authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 0
```

However, when I pass this Swagger definition into my CloudFormation script and call an endpoint secured with this authorizer, I get a 500.  The API Gateway logs show the following:

```
Incoming identity: ***key
Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid permissions on Lambda function
Execution failed due to configuration error: Authorizer error
```

Note that I *have* given API Gateway permission to execute this lambda:

```
LambdaPermissionAuthorizerApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - ApiKeyAuthorizerLambdaFunction
      - Arn
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

In fact, when I compare the CloudFormation script which Serverless generates for authoized endpoints (using Serverless's notation) with my own CloudFormation script using Swagger, I see little difference between them, *except* that my authorizer is defined with Swagger rather than directly as a CF resource.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  Is this a bug when using Swagger with CloudFormation?

Comment: Could you please post the configuration for one of the endpoints that uses the authorizer?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think we did, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the `authorizerCredentials` parameter of your `x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer` to a valid IAM role that has permission to execute the authorizer lambda? Not sure the standard `AWS::Lambda::Permission` applies for this, though you probably want to keep it for now just in case it is still required.

The [`x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-authorizer.html) show an example.